# If every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$, then $S$ is bounded

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$, then $S$ is bounded.

**Proof:** Suppose $S$ is unbounded. then , for every $m >0,~~\exists~~x_m \in S$ s.t. $|x_m|>m.$ The collection of $T=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is an infinite subset of $S$.

Hence, by the given statement, $T$ has an accumulation point $y$ in $T$.

But, for $m> 1+|y|$, we have $|x_m-y| \geq |x_m|-|y| > m-|y|>1$  contradicting the fact that $y$ is an accumulation point of $T$.

This proves that $T$ is bounded.

> **Query:** What happens when $S$ has only a finite number of unbounded elements in $S$ , that is, if we remove these finite number of unbounded elements from $S$, isn't it possible that $S$ might become a bounded set?
>
> Then, we won't be able to define the set $T$ as collection of infinite elements and neither the accumulation point of $T$ as $y$. Why hasn't the proof accomodated this possibility also?

Thank you for your help..

Comment: What is an unbounded element in $S$?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to talk about 'unbounded elements'.  Sets can be unbounded, but to be unbounded it is necessary (but not sufficient) for the set to be infinite.

Comment: @paw88789 uhm, if I consider a set $\{x_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ such that only $x_1 \rightarrow \infty $ and all the other elements are bounded, can we still apply the same proof?

Comment: @Pedro I understand that $S$ is unbounded means, for every $m>0$, there exists $x_m \in S$ s.t $|x_m|>M$. But, what happens when the set has only one element $x_1$ which tends to $\infty$ and all the rest of the elements are bounded?

Comment: @VHP: If $x_1$ is a fixed element, how can it go to $\infty$.  It would be like writing: $2\to\infty$.

Comment: @paw88789 My bad. But, what I meant was that suppose there is only one element $x_m$ or say only a finite number of elements $x_i 's $ such that $|x_i|>M ~\forall M>0$. What happens then?

Comment: @paw88789 I might be confused and not thinking the right way. What do you think? Is this a valid question?

Comment: @VHP: I am imagining that we are working in a metric space (possibly $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ since you are using notation $|x|$).  In $\mathbb{R}$ if $S$ is a subset in which there are only finitely many elements with $|x|>M$, then $S$ is bounded.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say that the set $S$ is bounded if we remove a finite number of so-called unbounded elements of it. Then, $S$ is bounded in $B_{r^{*}}(x)$ for some $x \in S$. Now, let $X = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ be the countable set of all unbounded elements. Let $r = max\{||x - x_i||; x_i \in X\}$, now for every $\rho > r$, the set $S$ is bounded in $B_\rho(x)$.

Comment: What is an unbounded element in $S\,$?

Comment: Actually there exists no such a thing as unbounded element. But as is mentioned in the problem itself, let's say there are some finite number of elements, stopping the set from being bounded, I have proved that it is not possible thus, the set is bounded.